# Why im getting an error that DocumentElement is not exist?

Tags: c#

```
private void Extract(string url)
{
    HtmlWeb hw = new HtmlWeb();
    HtmlDocument doc = hw.Load(url);
    foreach (HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//a[@href]"))
    {

    }
}
```

I want to extract/parse all the links from an html file.
But im getting an error:

> Error 8   'HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument' does not contain a definition
>   for 'DocumentElement' and no extension method 'DocumentElement'
>   accepting a first argument of type 'HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument'
>   could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)

EDIT**

I did this:

```
private void Extract(string url)
        {
            StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(@"d:\localpath\test.txt");
            HtmlWeb hw = new HtmlWeb();
            HtmlDocument doc = hw.Load(url);
            foreach (HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]"))
            {  
                w.WriteLine(link);
            }
            w.Close();
        }
```

And use it:

```
Extract(@"d:\localpath\Sat24_Cloudsheight_Europe.html");
```

But what im getting is many times the same line:

HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode

How do i write to the text file the parsed links ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change `DocumentElement` to `DocumentNode`